# Filling out XFA PDF using iTextSharp, data not saving (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, xfa

I have an XFA PDF file (which I did not author). It's a third-party form which I'm trying to fill out. I filled out the form manually, then I used iTextSharp save the full XML DomDocument from it. Now I'm trying to apply that same XML file programmatically. However, the resulting PDF doesn't have any of the fields filled in. This is the code I'm using to apply the XML file:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms, '\0', true))
    {
        XfaForm xfaForm = new XfaForm(pdfReader);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(inputXml);
        xfaForm.DomDocument = doc;
        xfaForm.Changed = true;
        XfaForm.SetXfa(xfaForm, stamper.Reader, stamper.Writer);
    }

    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputPdf, bytes);
}
```

inputPdf is the path to the original empty PDF file.

inputXml is the path to the XML file extracted from the filled out PDF file. This is the entire XML file, and not just the datasets section.

What's interesting is that if I create the PdfStamper object like this instead:

```
new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);
```

then I see the data in the fields, but of course then I have the associated issues with not appending.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? I just can't seem to get any of the changes to the DomDocument to save.

Comment: I should mention that the XML file has edits in the <xfa:datasets> section, the <form> section, and the <template> section.